# Can anyone explain the underlined content in the image?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, applications

[image: exact photo from book]

I understood everything except the thing inside the red bracket which states that *"The derivative f'(x) can change its sign only at values of x where f'(x) =0 or f'(x) is undefined or f(x) is discontinuous."* How can derivative exist at the point wheref(x) is discontinuous and when and how f'(x) can change its sign, i could not get it. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means that for example the derivative could be positive, then it could be undefined and when it is defined again it is negative

Comment: I guess it would make sense if "at values of x" is replaced with "from that values of x where..."

Comment: Your right, it doesnt really make sense to say it changes a sign when it isnt even defined at that point, but what I said above is what it is meaning to explain

Comment: I get your point too. Thanks pal #Quality